# IE 8 Script438 error

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, swfobject

Internet Explorer 8 again...

I've been looking around for solutions to my SCRIPT438 error (SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method) but none of them seem to work for me.

I'm working with swfobject.js and the error report on the F12 console says that there's an error on line 435 character 5, this line :

```
el.outerHTML = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"' + att + '>' + par + '</object>';
```

That line is part of this function:

```
function createSWF(attObj, parObj, id) {
    var r, el = getElementById(id);
    if (ua.wk && ua.wk < 312) { return r; }
    if (el) {
    if (typeof attObj.id == UNDEF) { // if no 'id' is defined for the object element, it will inherit the 'id' from the alternative content
        attObj.id = id;
    }
    if (ua.ie && ua.win) { // Internet Explorer + the HTML object element + W3C DOM methods do not combine: fall back to outerHTML
        var att = "";
        for (var i in attObj) {
            if (attObj[i] != Object.prototype[i]) { // filter out prototype additions from other potential libraries
                if (i.toLowerCase() == "data") {
                    parObj.movie = attObj[i];
                }
                else if (i.toLowerCase() == "styleclass") { // 'class' is an ECMA4 reserved keyword
                    att += ' class="' + attObj[i] + '"';
                }
                else if (i.toLowerCase() != "classid") {
                    att += ' ' + i + '="' + attObj[i] + '"';
                }
            }
        }
        var par = "";
        for (var j in parObj) {
            if (parObj[j] != Object.prototype[j]) { // filter out prototype additions from other potential libraries
                par += '<param name="' + j + '" value="' + parObj[j] + '" />';
            }
        }
        el.outerHTML = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"' + att + '>' + par + '</object>';
        objIdArr[objIdArr.length] = attObj.id; // stored to fix object 'leaks' on unload (dynamic publishing only)
        r = getElementById(attObj.id);  
    }
```

So 'el' should not be undefinied

This is how i add all my javascript to the HTML

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script src="js/player.js"></script>
```

I don't include jquery twice, the jquery.placeholder is a plugin i use to solve placeholder issues with ie9 in the source code can be found here 
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

I have to solve this untill monday, could really use some help

Comment: What kind of element does "el" refer to?

Comment: given that the swfobject.js should replace a div in my html i'll assume that el refers to a div...pretty sure that's the correct answer
Sorry if i've not provided enough info to solve the problem, i'm kinda of new to the Web programming scenario, pretty familiar with desktop/mobile programming though

Comment: Well you can tell what kind of element it is by looking at where your function is called and figuring out what "id" value is being passed.

Comment: I was right before...i call the swfobject constructor passing the id of a div

Comment: Ah OK. I asked because there are some elements for which IE won't do `outerHTML` (like `<td>` and obvious ones like `<body>`).

Comment: I've managed to solve the script 438 error using jquery;
replacing the el.outerHTML with $(el).replaceWith(update) where update is the whole '<object classid ... >' thing....but the video won't play on ie8, working fine on every other browser

Answer (score 0):

In a practical sense, and if you use compilation for your project, you might consider to install polyfill package

```
npm i --save core-js
```

or

```
yarn add core-js
```

Then to add at the top of your entry point of your project

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support